# How to disable multiple tabs for webview in .net Maui IOS application?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, maui

I am trying to disable multiple tabs in webview for IOS in .net maui. I was able to implement for android. Could please help for IOS.

I have tried below solution for android and it is working.

```
public class AndroidWebViewHandler : WebViewHandler
{
    protected override void ConnectHandler(global::Android.Webkit.WebView platformView)
    {
        platformView.Settings.SetSupportMultipleWindows(false);
        platformView.Settings.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = true;

        platformView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
        base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Maui.Handlers;
#if IOS
using WebKit;
#endif
namespace MauiApp5
{
    public class IOSWebViewHandler: WebViewHandler
    {
#if IOS
        protected override void ConnectHandler( WKWebView platformView)
        {
            platformView.MultipleTouchEnabled = false;
            platformView.Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically = false;
            platformView.Configuration.DefaultWebpagePreferences.AllowsContentJavaScript = true;
            //platformView.Configuration.Preferences.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
            base.ConnectHandler(platformView);
        }
#endif
    }
}
```